# C++11: std::thread pooled?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

In C++03 I used pthread with a self-built thread pool that always kept a couple of threads running (since `pthread_create` is slow), this way I was able to launch threads for small tasks without thinking about performance issues.

Now, in C++11 we have `std::thread`. I guess the standard doesn't say anything about the specific implementation, so my question is about the standard library implementations. Are they generally opting for a pooled approach where constructing `std::thread`s is cheap (and e.g. doesn't call `pthread_create` on posix), or will `std::thread` just be a wrapper?

In other words, is a thread pool still recommended in C++11, or should I just create a `std::thread` whenever I need one and leave performance up to the standard library?

Comment: `std::thread` creation can cost quite a bit and it differs substantially between different OS.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Generally, `std::thread` should be a minimal wrapper around underlying system primitive. For example, if you're on `pthread` platform, you can test with the following program that no matter how many threads you create, they are all created with unique `pthread_t` ids (which implies they're created on the fly and not borrowed from a thread pool):

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <set>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

#include <pthread.h>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::thread> workers;
  std::set<long long> thread_ids;
  std::mutex m;
  const int n = 1024;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    workers.push_back(std::thread([&] {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
      thread_ids.insert(pthread_self());
    }));
  }
  for (auto& worker : workers) {
    worker.join();
  }
  assert(thread_ids.size() == n);

  return 0;
}
```

So thread pools still make perfect sense. That said, I've seen a video where C++ committee members discussed thread pools with regard to `std::async` (IIRC), but I can't find it right now.

Answer (score 18):

A `std::thread` is a thread of execution. Period. Where it comes from, how it gets there, whether there is some pool of "actual" threads, etc, is all irrelevant to the standard. As long as it acts like a thread, it could be a `std::thread`.

Now, odds are good that `std::thread` is a real-life OS thread, not something pulled from a thread pool or whatever. But C++11 does theoretically allow a `std::thread` to be implemented as a something pulled from a pool.

Comment: I understand that, my question was about the practical implementations that are out there.

Comment: _"As long as it acts like a thread, it could be a std::thread."_ Where "acts like a thread" means (among other things) that `thread_local` variables are created anew when the thread starts and destroyed when the thread stops running, so do not persist across threads even if there's an underlying pool of OS threads.

Answer (score 6):

`std::thread` is supposed to come extremely cheaply in terms of abstraction costs, it's low level stuff. As I understand it, standard library implementations are probably going to just wrap the underlying OS mechanisms as closely as possible so you can assume the overhead of thread creation to be similar or equivalent.

I don't know about any specific implementations but it is my secondhand understanding from reading *C++ Concurrency In Action* that the standard suggests they use the most efficient method practical. The author certainly seemed to think the cost would be more or less negligible compared to DIY.

The library's similar to Boost conceptually so I imagine using the Boost implementation to draw some conclusions wouldn't be too farfetched.

Basically, I don't think there's an answer for your question directly because it just isn't specified. While it sounds to me that we're gonna be more likely to see very thin wrapper implementations, I don't think library writers are restricted from using thread pools if it offers efficiency benefits.

Answer (score 2):

First, as you mentioned, C++ standard basically doesn't specify library implementation.
But an implementer of C++ standard library *shall* obey the "as-if" rule.

For instance, it means that constructor of `std::thread` shall behave ***as if*** new thread created whether a thin wrapper of underlying API or an efficient implementation such as thread-pool. (here, 'thread' means an abstract *thread of execution* in C++11 specification, not a concrete OS native thread)

On the thread-pool implementation;

- C++ compiler and library shall properly treat C++ thread specific resources (ie. `thread_local` variable), and they should work together cooperatively at runtime.
- Even if above condition has been satisfied, it seems impossible to co-work with OS specific thread resources (TLS for Windows, TSS for pthread, etc.).

So, I assume that most `std::thread` implementation is just wrapper of the underlying threading API.