# Why is there no thread pool in C++ standard library?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17, threadpool

Since C++11 there has been a surge in the amount of parallel/concurrent programming tools in C++: threads, async functions, parallel algorithms, coroutines… But what about a popular parallel programming pattern: [thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool)?

As far as I can see, nothing in the standard library implements this directly. Threading via `std::thread` can be used to implement a thread pool, but this requires manual labor. Asynchronous function via `std::async` can be launched either in a new thread (`std::launch::async`) or in the calling thread (`std::launch::deferred`).

I think `std::async` could've been easily made to support thread pooling: via another launch policy (`std::launch::thread_pool`) which executes the task in an implicitly created global thread pool; or there could be a `std::thread_pool` object plus an overload of `std::async` which takes a thread pool.

Was something like this considered, and if so, why was it rejected? Or is there a standard solution that I am missing?

Comment: Why are you certain `std::async` _doesn't_ use a thread pool?

Comment: Either because 1. It hasn't been proposed or 2. Such proposal hasn't been accepted.

Comment: I have no idea, think they wanted to keep stl restricted to more primitive building blocks. And no there isn't a standard solution, but I have one lying around.

Comment: @Useless It is implemenation specific. Only on windows with msvc a threadpool is used, other implementations dont use a threadpool.

Comment: it isnt *easy* to get a thread-pool into the standard. I dont know how it came in all details, but consider that C++11 introduced `std::thread` and only C++20 introduced `std::jthread`. I suppose that time was needed to gather experience with the new threading facilities before C++20 could introduce `std::jthread` and this is still low level. I'd expect higher level abstractions to be even less easy to stnadardize

Comment: There are a number of different types of thread pool, and choosing the "best" for some purpose requires pretty detailed knowledge of the application and (quite often) properties of the host system.    Those characteristics increase difficulty in getting agreement on what should be standardised.   Standardising support of a thread pool that is (say) well-tuned for windows but poorly tuned for other operating systems runs against core philosophies of C++.

Comment: @Useless, @P Kramer, it was my understanding that implementing `std::launch::async` via a thread pool would be incompliant with the standard, which requires to use [a new thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch). A thread pool wouldn't have the same behavior: (a) because of thread local variables (see François Andrieux answer); (b) because it can deadlock if there are N active tasks in a thread pool with N threads waiting on some queued async task to finish.
@P Kramer, do you know who MSVC implementation remedies these problems?

Comment: @Useless it's invalid to use a threadpool because of `std::future` which requires a *new* thread. In fact MSVC had to patch their `std::async` to *not* use a threadpool for that reason. Specifically http://eel.is/c++draft/futures#state-10 and related bits cause major headaches

Answer (score 6):

In principal `std::async` could use a thread pool and is seems to me that allowing this was the intention. But in practice the existence of `thread_local` makes it difficult.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) on `std::async` with `std::launch::async`:

> [...] execute the callable object `f` on a new thread of execution (with all thread-locals initialized) as if spawned by `std::thread(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...)` [...]

If the function contains any local `thread_local` variables, and if `std::async` used a thread pool, the behavior of running the function would `std::async` could be different from the behavior of `std::thread`.

One example may be that the `thread_local` might not have not have it's initial value the second time its called by the same thread. If you were to use `std::thread` instead, it would always have the initial value.

Another way the behavior would diverge is `thread_local` object's destructors would not run in the same way for `std::async` and `std::thread`. This is illustrated by Microsoft's attempt at using a thread pool, which I suspect scared off others from trying it. You can read about this non-conformance here : [In Visual Studio, `thread_local` variables' destructor not called when used with std::async, is this a bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50897768/in-visual-studio-thread-local-variables-destructor-not-called-when-used-with).

To be completely conforming, the implementation would need to "reset" all the `thread_local` objects anyway. This requires compiler support and starts to look an awful lot like starting a new thread anyway.

Comment: Direct link to the bug in MSVC's Stdlib https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/949